# Custom Cropping of image is not working correctly

Tags: android

I am using the following code to perform the cropping of image in android.

But I am getting the wrong results. I am getting very zoom pictures,i think there is something wrong in my code

code:

```
   package net.londatiga.android;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CropView extends ImageView {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int initial_size = 300;
    private static Point leftTop, rightBottom, center, previous;

    private static final int DRAG= 0;
    private static final int LEFT= 1;
    private static final int TOP= 2;
    private static final int RIGHT= 3;
    private static final int BOTTOM= 4;

    private int imageScaledWidth,imageScaledHeight;
    // Adding parent class constructors   
    public CropView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCropView();
    }

    public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        initCropView();
    }

    public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initCropView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(leftTop.equals(0, 0))
            resetPoints();
        canvas.drawRect(leftTop.x, leftTop.y, rightBottom.x, rightBottom.y, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();
        switch (eventaction) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                previous.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                break; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                if(isActionInsideRectangle(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    adjustRectangle((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    invalidate(); // redraw rectangle
                    previous.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                }
                break; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                previous = new Point();
                break;
        }         
        return true;
    }

    private void initCropView() {
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);  
        leftTop = new Point();
        rightBottom = new Point();
        center = new Point();
        previous = new Point();
    }

    public void resetPoints() {
        center.set(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        leftTop.set((getWidth()-initial_size)/2,(getHeight()-initial_size)/2);
        rightBottom.set(leftTop.x+initial_size, leftTop.y+initial_size);
    }

    private static boolean isActionInsideRectangle(float x, float y) {
        int buffer = 10;
        return (x>=(leftTop.x-buffer)&&x<=(rightBottom.x+buffer)&& y>=(leftTop.y-buffer)&&y<=(rightBottom.y+buffer))?true:false;
    }

    private boolean isInImageRange(PointF point) {
        // Get image matrix values and place them in an array
        float[] f = new float[9];
        getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

        // Calculate the scaled dimensions
        imageScaledWidth = Math.round(getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() * f[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
        imageScaledHeight = Math.round(getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() * f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);

        return (point.x>=(center.x-(imageScaledWidth/2))&&point.x<=(center.x+(imageScaledWidth/2))&&point.y>=(center.y-(imageScaledHeight/2))&&point.y<=(center.y+(imageScaledHeight/2)))?true:false;
    }

    private void adjustRectangle(int x, int y) {
        int movement;
        switch(getAffectedSide(x,y)) {
            case LEFT:
                movement = x-leftTop.x;
                if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement)))
                    leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement);
                break;
            case TOP:
                movement = y-leftTop.y;
                if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement)))
                    leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movement);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                movement = x-rightBottom.x;
                if(isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement)))
                    rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement);
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                movement = y-rightBottom.y;
                if(isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement)))
                    rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movement);
                break;      
            case DRAG:
                movement = x-previous.x;
                int movementY = y-previous.y;
                if(isInImageRange(new PointF(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movementY)) && isInImageRange(new PointF(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movementY))) {
                    leftTop.set(leftTop.x+movement,leftTop.y+movementY);
                    rightBottom.set(rightBottom.x+movement,rightBottom.y+movementY);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private static int getAffectedSide(float x, float y) {
        int buffer = 10;
        if(x>=(leftTop.x-buffer)&&x<=(leftTop.x+buffer))
            return LEFT;
        else if(y>=(leftTop.y-buffer)&&y<=(leftTop.y+buffer))
            return TOP;
        else if(x>=(rightBottom.x-buffer)&&x<=(rightBottom.x+buffer))
            return RIGHT;
        else if(y>=(rightBottom.y-buffer)&&y<=(rightBottom.y+buffer))
            return BOTTOM;
        else
            return DRAG;
    }

    public byte[] getCroppedImage() {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)getDrawable();
        float x = leftTop.x-center.x+(drawable.getBitmap().getWidth()/2);
        float y = leftTop.y-center.y+(drawable.getBitmap().getHeight()/2);
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getBitmap(),(int)x,(int)y,(int)rightBottom.x-(int)leftTop.x,(int)rightBottom.y-(int)leftTop.y);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

The image which I tried to do crop is

[image]

The expected image is what is there in the rectangular box but I am getting very zoomed image

resulted image

[image]

How can I solve this issue,I tried by changing some code but didnt find any results.

And Another issue is that by using this Rectangle box I can able to crop images only in Rectangle shapes, is there any possibility to  crop image in any shape which I want.

I have observed this in one of the app ( Document Scanner trail version ),in which user can able to crop image in some irregular shapes using the same rectangle box.

How can I achieve this result?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: 3rd party library also there. You can use it to save time.

Comment: can you please tell me that

Comment: I stucked in the middle,did I need to send all the data like aspectx,aspecty and all others

Comment: no.. you don't. It will automatically take. You can leave implementation. But I have successfully implemented this myself. And also I stucked at that time for 3 days. :)

Comment: I have kept an Log message in cropImage Activity,it is successfully going there, but that activity is expecting more fields in the form of extras and this activity is not starting,can I crop the image in any shapes like not only in rectangular forms.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try that. Download link is also changed.

Comment: can you able to crop in any shapes?

Comment: no my friend . It only support rectangle. I also searched for circle crop. It is possible. but not all shapes.

Comment: I have a  requirement of cropping into different shapes, could you please see the Document Scanner trail app which is free

Comment: isn't your problem solved yet?

Comment: no, I didnt solved, did you see that camscanner app in android,which is doing cropping in very efficient way

Comment: see my application on store named "i2cam". Crop image, you will get your answer.

Comment: please see the camscanner app,I just want to do that functionality

Comment: I have seen your i2cam app,I think you have just used intent calling Crop coming with camera. Did you see the app which I said?

Comment: Its not camera intent my friend. Its implementation of library which i answered. Although its camera code of API 1.6 which is deprecated now. But we can use that code.

Comment: did you see the app which I said?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented **[Android Crop Image](https://github.com/MMP-forTour/cropimage)** library. Which is very helpful to me. It has following features.

1. Pinch zoom to crop very small portion of image
2. Rectangle which is resizable over image
3. Efficient Image Crop result back to your activity
4. Rotation facility

**Edit**

For result,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (data != null) if (data.getParcelableExtra("data") != null)
     Bitmap bitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
}
```

**One more Edit**

Search `private void handleFace(FaceDetector.Face f)` method in `CropImage` file. Put following code inside method after `HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);` this line.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Also add above code in `private void makeDefault()` method.

```
 private void makeDefault(){
    HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
     //rest of code
}
```

Due to some reason of acceleration, this is necessary. If you get any error in "GINGERBREAD" and "View.LAYOUT_TYPE_SOFTWARE", then change your API version to 4.0 and above.

Make sure you have activity registration like below,

```
<activity
        android:name="com.android.camera.CropImage"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

**Note**

This sample application has dirty layout. You need to make clear yourself. This is library project, so remove "is library" from project property to run that sample code.

Comment: MenuHelper class is not recognized,mLeft,mContext,mRight variables are not recognized

Comment: @ChintanRathod , Upvoted How can I use this library in my project. I have included it in my project. please provide a tutorial link or tell me in step wise thank u

Comment: no laucher activity found errors,did I need to add any others in manifest

Comment: Its obvious my dear. You need to register Activity.

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".CropImage"
            
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: I have added my activity here,but my application is just starting and then closing,I cannot able to view a single screen

Comment: There is no CamActivity in the project,where should I add the above code mentioned

Comment: But you did wrong thing, you need to pass some data before starting activity. You have to call that activity from other activity. So that you can pass other data like path and other extras to Crop activity. Don't make CropImage as Main Activity. You need to create other activity which has button inside, which call CropImage activity with parameters.

Comment: Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
              selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
       Log.e("imagepath",selectedImagePath);
       
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        CropImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("image-path",selectedImagePath);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);

Comment: I used the above code in my onActivityResult,but I couldnt able to go into next Activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33186/discussion-between-user2376732-and-chintan-rathod)

Comment: its not croping my image yaar.? here is my file path /mnt/sdcard/scroll.PNG i have checked this exits and this is the logcat now Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.android_croptest/com.android.camera.CropImage (has extras) } from pid 6008, I m setting the result bitmap in an imageview but its showing blank not the croped version of my image. what should i do @ChintanRathod

Comment: String imgPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     .getPath() + "/scroll.PNG";

   File filePath = new File(imgPath);
   if (filePath.exists()) {
    Log.i("Test", imgPath);

    Intent cropIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
      com.android.camera.CropImage.class);

    cropIntent.putExtra("image-path", imgPath);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP);

   }

Comment: @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == CROP) {

   if (data != null)
    if (data.getParcelableExtra("data") != null)
     btmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
   imgView.setImageBitmap(btmap);
   Log.i("Test", "Executed If");

  }

 }

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Not yet bro. please help out

Comment: @QadirHussain, I edited my whole answer. Link is also another application. Download and follow instruction as i written. Hope this time your problem solved.

Comment: @ChintanRathod sample is working fine for me.i have one issue after rotate to right and crop the image.cropped image is showing the black color edged?how to solve this?

Comment: @Rajesh can you share some code. I have my shared code https://github.com/rathodchintan/ResizableRectangleOverlay here. You can either apply to merge or share a new repo so that I can help you

Comment: @ChintanRathod Thanks for your reply, i am facing the another issue in cropping.That is after cropping my image resolution is decrease.For example original image resolution is 1600X1200 but after crop the resolution decreased to 850X850.How to crop the image with out decreasing the image resolution?